# How to fix form, input default overflow behaviour

Tags: css, html, xhtml

When I put an `input` of type `text` inside a `form` the `input` overflows the `form` by `4 pixels`; this only seems to occur when `width` is `100%`.

**id est**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      input { width: 100% }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form><input type="text" /></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does this occur?

http://jsfiddle.net/3y8bmqfw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because most browsers create a 2px border around `<input type="text">` elements. 2px left + 2px right = 4px. Since the width does not count the border, if width = 100% of the container width, the 4px of border overflows the container.

One possible way to correct this is to apply `box-sizing: border-box` to the element to have the browser calculate the size of the box differently (including padding and border).